# How to get the arrayobject based on condition in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter, foreach

I would like to know how to find duplicates in fields and based on c

conditions get  array object using javascript.

from arrayobj, get same property `model`,then check

if typecode value is same but not `SP`, model same return that arrayobject

if typecode value has `SP`, model same return that arrayobject
else return []

for arrobj,

```
if model and typecode has same value, return those array object

if model same, any object typecode has value SP return those array

if above two conditions fails, return empty array
```

```
var arrobj1=[
   {id:1, model: "interior", name: "lisa", typecode: "FL"},
   {id:2, model: "interior", name: "peter", typecode: "FL"},
   {id:3, model: "exterior", name: "john", typecode: "SP"}
]
var result1=isValid(arrobj1);
Expected Output
// result1
[
  {id:1, model: "interior", name: "lisa", typecode: "FL"},
  {id:2, model: "interior", name: "peter", typecode: "FL"}
]


var arrobj2=[
   {id:1, model: "exterior", name: "lisa", typecode: "FL"},
   {id:2, model: "interior", name: "peter", typecode: "FP"},
   {id:3, model: "interior", name: "john", typecode: "SP"}
]
var result2=isValid(arrobj2);
Expected Output
// result2
[
  {id:2, model: "interior", name: "peter", typecode: "FP"},
   {id:3, model: "interior", name: "john", typecode: "SP"}
]

function isValid(list){
     let result=[];
    let duplicates = list.map((item, index) =>{
    return list.find((x, ind)=> x.model === item.model && index !== ind );
  })
   duplicates.forEach(e=>{
    if(e.typecode !== "SP"){
     result.push(e);
    }
  })
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Took a little time to understand your conditions,

This code should do it, hope you understand it

```
var arrobj1 = [
    { id: 1, model: "interior", name: "lisa", typecode: "FL" },
    { id: 2, model: "interior", name: "peter", typecode: "FL" },
    { id: 3, model: "exterior", name: "john", typecode: "SP" }
];

var arrobj2 = [
    { id: 1, model: "exterior", name: "lisa", typecode: "FL" },
    { id: 2, model: "interior", name: "peter", typecode: "FP" },
    { id: 3, model: "interior", name: "john", typecode: "SP" }
];

const isValid = (arr) => {
    const modelArrays = [];
    const modelArraysCount = {};

    const typecodeArrays = [];
    const typecodeArraysCount = {};

    arr.forEach(item => {
        modelArrays.push(item.model)
        typecodeArrays.push(item.typecode)
    });

    modelArrays.forEach(model => {
        if (modelArraysCount[model]) {
            modelArraysCount[model] += 1;
        } else {
            modelArraysCount[model] = 1;
        }
    });

    typecodeArrays.forEach(typecode => {
        if (typecodeArraysCount[typecode]) {
            typecodeArraysCount[typecode] += 1;
        } else {
            typecodeArraysCount[typecode] = 1;
        }
    });
    
    // console.log(modelArraysCount)
    // console.log(typecodeArraysCount)
    // console.log(modelArraysCount[0])

    var modelResult;
    for (const key in modelArraysCount) {
        if (modelArraysCount[key] === Math.max(...Object.values(modelArraysCount))) {
            modelResult = key;
            break;
        }
    }

    var typecodeResult;
    for (const key in typecodeArraysCount) {
        if (typecodeArraysCount[key] === Math.max(...Object.values(typecodeArraysCount))) {
            typecodeResult = key;
            break;
        }
    }

    // console.log(modelArraysCount, typecodeArraysCount)

    return arr.filter(i => {
        return (i.model == modelResult && i.typecode == typecodeResult) || (i.model == modelResult);
    })
}

console.log(isValid(arrobj2))
```

And I didn't understand your second condition about the model being the same and SP and all but tried to fulfill your required output.

> Please do let me know if there is any confusion. Thank you

Comment: thanks a lot for taking time for solution, I have tried in a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/miyavv/jcag0fm1/ in a loop way, in fiddle solution, i got stuck instead of true how to get array values, if possible can help, thanks in advance

Comment: fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/miyavv/jcag0fm1/6/